# LibGdx: How to make a body rotate in response to a linear impulse applied away from the center of the body?

Tags: java, android-studio, libgdx, box2d, game-physics

I heard that calling ApplyLinearImpulse to a body at the center would not cause rotation, which means that applying it at any other point should cause the body to rotate right? I tried doing so but the body still does not rotate according to the fixture drawn by the Box2DDebugRenderer. Do I need to provide any additional setup for rotation of the body to work in response to applyLinearImpulse? Does Libgdx automatically take care of rotation as a result of forces/torque or do we have to implement these kinds of rotations ourselves?

Comment: i think you can calculate angle and use rotate actions : RotateBy  or RotateTo

Comment: what type of shape are you using?

Comment: I am using a circle shape